# How can I remove columns from a QTreeView (using QDirModel)?

Tags: user-interface, qt, qt4

I have a QDirModel attached to a QTreeView and I only want to see the paths, not size, type and date modified.

Is there a way to remove these columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`QTreeView::setColumnHidden(int column, bool hide)` should do the trick.

Comment: Searching for this option made me go nuts...
Thanks a million for the perfect solution.

Answer (score 0):

One can also use [`hideColumn()`](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt4/qtreeview.html#hideColumn). Something like:

```
for i in range(1, self.my_tree_view.header().length()):
    self.my_tree_view.hideColumn(i)
```