# PyQt: removing QTreeView columns

Tags: python, qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel, qheaderview

I am using QTreeView with QFileSystemModel. It displays columns like Size, Type, Modification Date, which I don't need. How can I remove them from the view? I can't find any `removeColumn` in model or in view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get the [`QHeaderView`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html) of your TreeView by calling header() on it, the headerview knows about the columns and can hide them via [`hideSection`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#hideSection).

Answer (score 7):

I believe, this post is a duplicate of:
[How can I remove columns from a QTreeView (using QDirModel)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4203022/1082289)

The only difference is that here we are using QFileSystemModel instead of QDirModel - which makes no difference since the columns needs to be hidden in the view.

So I believe pointing to the right solution is the best thing to do.

```
QTreeView::setColumnHidden(int column, bool hide)
```