# QTreeView with QFileSystemModel: How can I remove all columns except "Name"?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

while I'm working on something in Qt5 that closely resembles a file manager, I try to implement a *very basic* tree view, showing only the directory names without any other information. However, (it seems that) `QTreeView` doesn't let me decide which columns I want to show.

Here's what I have:

```
// ...
QString m_path = "C:/Users/mine";

dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
dirModel->setRootPath(m_path);

ui->treeView->setModel(dirModel);
// ...
```

Now my `QTreeView` shows more information with the name, like the size et al.; however, this is not the desired behavior.

Setting `headerVisible` to `false` removes the "headline" of my `QTreeView` which is OK, but how can I remove the other columns completely? I tried:

```
ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
```

just to test if that works, but it did not change a thing.

Comment: `hideColumn` does what you are trying to do. Are you sure you called it *after* the model was initialized? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#hideColumn

Comment: I try to use it after `setModel`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
QTreeView* treeView = new QTreeView(centralWidget());
QFileSystemModel* fsModel = new QFileSystemModel(treeView);
fsModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
fsModel->setRootPath("/home/user");
treeView->setModel(fsModel);
// first column is the name
for (int i = 1; i < fsModel->columnCount(); ++i)
    treeView->hideColumn(i);

QHBoxLayout* hLayout = new QHBoxLayout(centralWidget());
hLayout->addWidget(treeView);
```

---

Another approach here (PyQt but the logic is still the same): [PyQt: removing unnecessary columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413595/pyqt-removing-unnecessary-columns)

Comment: hides all the columns except the first (name) column.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your approach. It works as below:

mainwindow header:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QFileSystemModel * dirModel;
};
```

mainwindow source:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString m_path = "E:";

    dirModel = new QFileSystemModel(this);
    dirModel->setFilter(QDir::NoDotAndDotDot | QDir::AllDirs);
    dirModel->setRootPath(m_path);

    ui->treeView->setModel(dirModel);

    ui->treeView->hideColumn(1);
}
```

Comment: It does not hide any columns though ... :-/

Comment: Can you post a major section of your code, because the above code hides the "Size" column on my computer.

Comment: Hmm, are the columns identical for all Windows versions?

Comment: Probably not, you should check the text

Comment: Then it might be even more difficult to find the correct columns to remove, right? :(

Comment: Solved for me. hideColumn after setModel work fine! Thanks!